# Is there a way to use Cognos SDK to manipulate a BIBusTKServer?

Tags: cognos

All our packages are published in CQM mode. CQM queries use the 32-bit version of the Bi Bus process, this BI bus is limited to 2 GB of memory. This causes some large reports to fail with out of memory errors

> CCL-SRV-0513 The BIBusTKServer process ran out of memory

The solution would be to publish in DQM but that is throwing another error that requires an upgrade. We are not ready for an upgrade now.

So my question is: Is there a way to use Cognos SDK to manipulate a BIBusTKServer? We want to be able to change the maximum allowed memory for CQM queries from 2 GB to any other value.

Comment: You can't. 32 bit processes can't address more than 2Gb of memory. If there was a way to do it, IBM would have already done it... well it's only been 5 years or so since DQM so maybe not......

Comment: You might want to consider rewriting your reports to be less memory intensive. Break up into smaller reports. Make sure queries are efficient. Make sure you aren't doing data dumps via Cognos.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid,  Just grasping at straws. Yea, Cognos would have done it if they could. The problem with our reports is the large dependence on custom sql to accelerate the development time but on the expense of memory usage.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, I will accept your comments as an answer if you submit it

Comment: What is a "large report"?  What is causing the excessive memory usage?  I have reports that take over 30 minutes to run and produce over 300 columns by about 200,000 rows of output (Cognos as an ETL tool) and I have never seen that error message, so output quantity is not a contributor.  I also have reports with over 30 queries joined and unioned pulling from multiple data sources, so complexity doesn't appear to be a contributor.  Are you using data sets, modules, packages?  Custom SQL should push more of the work to the database server, so Cognos should be doing less work.

Comment: What is your database/datasource?  For example you might be able to pre-build some of the queries or create an MQT (materialized query table) pre-aggregating and pre-calculating things

Comment: Encoded vector index (EVI) may be something you want to explore as well. They are system maintained, so the data is always up to date

Comment: Does a single run of a report cause the OOM error or is it multiple requests that aggregate to cause the error?  If it is multiple requests, you could consider adding more dispatcher nodes with 32-bit report servers and distributing the request load that way.

Answer (score 0):

Usually if the BIBus runs out of memory on generating output you would experience a CCL OOM, the error you are getting might be related to tuning.  If you are on linux ensure your ulimits are set correctly.

https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/ccl-srv-0514-bibustkserver-process-ran-out-thread-resource

You may also want to watch the process while running the report to see how much memory it actually uses.